# throwing a derived class object as exception object.it is not caught by a base class object type catch block .Why so?

Tags: inheritance, exception, derived-class, base-class

I m throwing a derived class object as exception. i have a catch block with base class object type parameter and a catch all block.
I have inherited the base class as private.
I excpected that the catch block expecting a base class object will catch the exception.But thats not the case.
when i inherit the base class publicly it works as expected.
why does private inheritence change the working of the catch block.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class MyExcept1 {
public:
    int a;
};
class MyExcept2:MyExcept1{
public:    
    int b;
}; 
int main()
{
    try{
        MyExcept2 myexp1;
       throw myexp1;
    }
    catch(MyExcept1 e2){
        cout << "Caught MyExcept2 " << endl;
    }
    catch(...){
        cout << " Defaule catch block " << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: write the code first to understand

Comment: Does inherting a class privately prevent a  catch block for base type objects to catch an exception of a derived class type?